# How to convert string returned by AJAX into javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm using jqGrid and would like to use the ajax return from Coldfusion to build the colModel array.

When I create the array cm on the client like below, this works.

```
function subTab(obj,id,tab){
var param={id:id,tab:tab}
http('POST','cfc/view/'+obj+'.cfc?method=view',subTab_RTN,param);
}
function subTab_RTN(obj){
$("#detail").html(obj.html);
if(obj.grid.display){
var cm;
switch(obj.grid.tab){
case "docs":
cm=[{name:'contactID',index:'contactID',hidden:true},
{name:'docName',index:'docName',width:200,label:'Document Name'},
{name:'docType',index:'docType',width:200,label:'Document Type'},
{name:'campaign',index:'campaign',width:200,label:'Campaign'},
{name:'campaignCode',index:'campaignCode',width:125,label:'Campaign Code'},
{name:'campaignType',index:'campaignType',width:125,label:'Campaign Type'},
{name:'downloadDate',index:'downloadDate',width:125,label:'Download     Date',formatter:'date'}];
break;
}
$("#subTabGridTbl").jqGrid({
url:obj.grid.url, 
datatype: "json", 
colModel:cm,
...
```

I would prefer however to create the array on the server like:

```
 <cfset rtn.grid.cols="[{name:'contactID',index:'contactID',hidden:true},
 {name:'docName',index:'docName',width:200,label:'Document Name'},
 {name:'docType',index:'docType',width:200,label:'Document Type'},
 {name:'campaign',index:'campaign',width:200,label:'Campaign'},
 {name:'campaignCode',index:'campaignCode',width:125,label:'Campaign Code'},
 {name:'campaignType',index:'campaignType',width:125,label:'Campaign Type'},
 {name:'downloadDate',index:'downloadDate',width:125,label:'Download Date',formatter:'date'}]" />
```

and then use the returned obj (obj.grid.cols) to build the array.

Thanks for your help.
Gary

Comment: Make it valid JSON and then just parse it into a JS object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is [supported](http://caniuse.com/json) in most major browsers. If you need to support IE7 and below, I believe you can use [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to get the same result. Both methods require a well-formed JSON string.

As an aside, I'd recommend creating your array as a native CF array of structs and then using [`serializeJSON()`](http://cfdocs.org/serializejson) to convert it to a JSON string. This will help minimize any issues you'll run into by trying to write the JSON string by hand.

Comment: Thanks Sean and all,  making it valid JSON and using jQuery.parseJSON() made it work.  Building the array as a CF array of structs is a great idea and will help with other grids I'm using.  The only "gotcha" was that I had to use array notation when I created the structs.  Dot notation made the keys UPPER case which wasn't recognized by jqGrid.

Comment: Even better solution (IMHO): http('POST','cfc/view/'+obj+'.cfc?method=view&returnFormat=json',subTab_RTN,param); Then have the CFC method simply return the array of structs. This way if you ever happen to need to call that same method internally, you will get a ColdFusion array and NOT a JSON string.